# View Results Tree report not in correct execution order

Tags: jmeter

I executed multiple thread groups, each group having multiple samplers (requests).
Am not seeing order of execution in correct order on completion of final result.
I meant in the results tree all requests showing in correct order, but am expecting to see in correct order.

Is there any way to see complete report with correct order of execution?

Answer (score 0):

There is option `Run Thread Groups consecutively (i.e. run groups one at a time)` in Test Plan configuration - if that's something you are looking for.

Comment: Am using same thing what you mentioned above,under Test plan i have many thread groups and samplers,under each thread the report showing correct order of execution but final report after complete execution of all threads not printed in order of execution.my problem at the final report should be displayed(printed) all executions in correct order.